# Add Node To XML In PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am trying to add the node in xml file.
i want to add a new node after 'Self' like this

```
<NewNode>UN9TD72U</NewNode>
```

This is how my xml file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetProductCategories>
<GetProduct>
<Self>
<ProductCategoryId>1282779353</ProductCategoryId>
<ProductCategoryName>Shirt</ProductCategoryName>
<Parent>
<ProductCategoryId>8363437382</ProductCategoryId>
<ProductCategoryName>Sports tshirt</ProductCategoryName>
</Parent>
</Self>
</GetProduct>
</GetProductCategories>
```

My **Code** is:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
$child = $xml->addChild("NewNode");
$child->addAttribute("text","UN9TD72U");
$xml->asXML("data.xml");
```

**Output** i get is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetProductCategories>
<GetProduct>
<Self>
<ProductCategoryId>1282779353</ProductCategoryId>
<ProductCategoryName>Shirt</ProductCategoryName>
<Parent>
<ProductCategoryId>8363437382</ProductCategoryId>
<ProductCategoryName>Sports tshirt</ProductCategoryName>
</Parent>
</Self>
</GetProduct>
<NewNode text="UN9TD72U"/>
</GetProductCategories>
```

Comment: No ,It just has to be inside Self  or may be inside Parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addChild()` accepts a second parameter of value, so you can write:

```
$child = $xml->addChild("NewNode", "UN9TD72U");
```

As for adding it inside `<Self>` (I assume that's what you wanted?), you can go inside each object in the model with `children()`:

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comments by Iainn (I forgot this worked), you can also access child elements directly, such as `$xml->GetProduct->Self->addChild()`.

---

So to sum up:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
$xml->GetProduct->Self->addChild("NewNode", "UN9TD72U");
$xml->asXML("data.xml");
```

Comment: You don't need to use `children()` to access the deeper elements, `$xml->GetProduct->Self->addChild()` will work fine.

Comment: The way I read the question, they don't want to add it as an attribute, but as a value. That's part of the problem they were experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
$child = $xml->GetProduct->addChild("NewNode", "UN9TD72U");
$xml->asXML("curlrequestcategories.xml");
```